# transforming xml files in mvc application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, publishing, publish-profiles

I am working with a .net MVC4 web application. I use publish profiles to publish my application and all works nicely.

I transform the web.config, I set up a publish profile for each of the environments I am deploying to qa, production etc. The transform works perfectly when I build the package for particular environments.

Within my web application, I have number of other xml files that vary per environment. Is it possible to also transform these files for deployment? And if so, how might this be achieved?

Answer (score 0):

I believe [SlowCheetah](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/69023d00-a4f9-4a34-a6cd-7e854ba318b5) was designed for this purpose.